# Databricks - readstream from delta table writestream to orc file only with changes

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

A pipeline runs every 20 minutes pushing data to ADLS Gen2 storage in ORC format.

1. I have an Azure Databricks notebook job which runs every 1 hour.
   This job reads the orc file from ADLS as structured stream (orc file created by pipeline mentioned above), then uses the merge functionality to upsert data to delta table based on a primaryKey column.

```py
event_readstream = ( 
    spark.readStream
    .format("orc")
    .schema('my-schema.json')
    .load('/mnt/path/from/adls/to/orc/files/')
  )
  ...

def upsertEventToDeltaTable(df, batch_id): 
  input_df = (
    df
    .drop('address_line3')
    .dropDuplicates(['primaryKey'])
    .withColumn(partition_column, F.date_format(F.col('updateddate'), 'yyyy').cast('int'))
  )
  
  input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("event_df_updates")
  
  input_df._jdf.sparkSession().sql("""
    MERGE INTO events dbEvent
    USING event_df_updates dfEvent
    ON dbEvent.primaryKey = dfEvent.primaryKey
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *                     
                             """)

event_writestream = ( 
    event_readStream
    .drop('adddress_line3')  #some column to be dropped
    .repartition(1)
    .writeStream
    .trigger(once=True)
    .format("delta")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "{}/checkpoints/{}".format(adls_mount_path,mytable))
    .foreachBatch(upsertEventToDeltaTable)
    .start()
  )
```

2. The same notebook also uses the read stream (structured stream) and writes the data directly to a different location in ADLS Gen2 storage. This also uses the `forEachBatch()` from writestream with `checkpoint` options enabled.

```py
def loadToLocation(df, batch_id): 
  (
    df
    .repartition(1)
    .write
    .partitionBy('updateddate')
    .format("orc")
    .mode("append")
    .save('{}/event/data'.format(adls_mount_path))  
  )

location_writestream = ( 
  event_readstream   # Same read stream is used here 
  .writeStream
  .trigger(once=True)
  .option("checkpointLocation", "{}/checkpoints/event".format(adls_mount_path))
  .foreachBatch(loadToLocation)
  .start()
)
```

Question:

- The Delta table is upserts data every 1 hour in my case, if I create new readstream (reading from delta table ) and writestream (write to ORC file).
  will the ORC file contain only the changes that got merged in the delta table? [Details below]
- Is there any issues in this approach, if only the changed or updated data will be written to ORC file?

In above point #2, instead of using the readStream (reading from orc file), create a new readStream using the Delta table path like below

```py
deltatbl_event_readstream = spark.readStream.format("delta")
  .load("/mnt/delta/myadlsaccnt/user_events")  # my delta table location
```

- and use a different write stream like below

```py
def loadToLocation(df, batch_id): 
  (
    df
    .repartition(1)
    .write
    .partitionBy('updateddate')
    .format("orc")
    .mode("append")
    .save('{}/event/data'.format(adls_mount_path))  
  )

deltatbl_event_readstream
   .writeStream
  .trigger(once=True)
  .option("checkpointLocation", "{}/checkpoints/event".format(adls_mount_path))
  .foreachBatch(loadToLocation)  # re-using the same method.
  .start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the link [DATA+AI summit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsx11EKH6Hk) which has Demo for such scenario.

In my case, each batch has >90% new row, less updates. So i can't use this option. This might help others.

Below is similar to Alex Ott answer, have added additional info

Per recommendation, if batch updates are more, CDF might not be effective.

- To enable the CDF feature:

```sql
%sql
ALTER table <table-name> SET TBLPROPERTIES (delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true)
```

- Perform any update/insert operation the table
- use ***`table_changes()`*** function to view the changes

```sql
%sql 
select * from table_changes('<table-name>',<start-commit-version>,<end-commit-version>
```

- To read as stream

```py
event_read_stream = spark.readStream
     .format("delta")
     .option("readChangeFeed", "true")
     .option("startingVersion", "latest")
     .table("event") #// table name 
     .filter("_change_type != 'update_preimage'")
```

- Create the upsert function which merge the change
- write stream to write the info

```py
event_read_stream.writeStream.format("delta")
  .trigger(processingTime = "2 seconds") # if in case if job use once
  .outputMode("append")
  .start()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just use plain `readStream` on Delta table without any options, then you won't get information about updates. In fact, the stream will fail after update until you set option `ignoreChanges`. That's comes from the fact that Delta doesn't track changes, and when you make update/delete, it's rewriting existing files, so by looking into the file you just see the data, and don't know if it was insert or update.

But if you need to stream changes from Delta, then you can use [Delta Change Data Feed](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html) (CDF) functionality introduced in Delta 8.4 (if I remember correctly).  To make it working, you need to enable it on the source delta table by setting property `delta.enableChangeDataFeed` to `true`.  And since that version, you'll able to read feed of changes, with something like this:

```py
deltatbl_event_readstream = spark.readStream.format("delta")\
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
  .option("startingVersion", <version_of_delta_when_you_enable_cdf>) \
  .load("...")
```

this will add three additional columns that describe the operation performed, version of Delta, and timestamp. If you need to track only changes, you need to select only rows where the `_change_type` column has value `update_postimage`, and after that you can store that data in whatever you need.

But please take into account, that after you enable CDF on the table, the other clients (DBR < 8.4, OSS) won't be able to write into that table, although they will continue to read data.