# How to fetch the latest version number of a delta table

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

for one of my use cases I am using change data feed (CDF) feature of delta lake,it goes all well with CDF but when i read all the data to insert in gold, it lists all the versions, is there a way i can read only the latest version without specifying version number or a way to fetch latest version ?

```
        return spark.read.format("delta") \
                  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
                  .table(tableName) \
                  .where(col("_change_type") != "preimage")
```

above code block returns results from all versions since start, i can fetch only latest data by looking into the table and specifying the version but i don't understand how to enable this in production, I don't want to use timestamp to fetch the latest version as in case of retries some one might run the pipeline multiple times a day and this will bring data inaccuracies if not handled as 1st run of the day.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We can write a query for row level modifications to get the different versions of a delta table.

As [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3192775/tim) posted in [an answer to a similar Stack Overflow question](https://%5BSO%5D(https://stackoverflow.com/a/70227670/18935775)), you can read it as a stream like the following:

> ```py
> spark.readStream
>      .format("delta")
>      .option("readChangeFeed", "true")
>      .option("startingVersion", "latest")
>      .table(tableName) 
>      .filter("_change_type != 'update_preimage'")
> ```

Comment: eventually the "latest" tag isn't working for me, so i have used the history table to fetch the version specific to the day. Code snippet in another comment.

Comment: ` date_dict = self.calc_day(minus_n_days)
 process_date = date_dict['process_date']
 full_history_df = DeltaTable.forName(self.spark, table_name).history()
 latest_version_row = full_history_df.filter(to_date(col("timestamp")) == date_dict['process_date']).selectExpr("max(version)").collect() latest_version = latest_version_row[0][0]`

Comment: Hope you enabled the CDF feature i.e, **TBLPROPERTIES & table_changes()** as per the [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70227670/18935775)

Comment: yes, it's working correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from delta.tables import DeltaTable

table_path = "/path/to/your/delta/table"
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, table_path)

history_df = deltaTable.history() \
    .select("version") \
    .orderBy("version", ascending=False)

version = history_df.collect()[0][0]

df = spark.read \
    .format("delta") \
    .option("versionAsOf",version) \
    .load(delta_table_path)
```

Comment: Please note that code only answers might not be good enough, please add some explanations